# What is difference between "npx react-native run-android" vs "react-native run-android"

Tags: react-native

What is difference between **npx react-native run-android** vs **react-native run-android**

Answer (score 5):

There are currently two CLIs:

- `@react-native-community/cli` – the one used directly by react-native. That makes it a transitive dependency of your project.
- `react-native-cli` – an optional global convenience package, which is a proxy to @react-native-community/cli and global installation helper.

The global version is no longer recommended

- `npx` executes  either from a local `node_modules/.bin`, or from a central cache, installing any packages needed in order for  to run.
- When you run `npx ...` it picks up the cli package that is part of your project dependency