# Why metro builder is opening for new react native version in my old project? And facing Cannot find module 'expo-asset/tools/hashAssetFiles'

Tags: react-native

I recently initialized a new bare react-native project(initialized as version 0.70.6). And now I am facing this issue on my old react-native project.

And I am getting an error when the app runs. Error is `error: src/res/images/play.png: Cannot find module 'expo-asset/tools/hashAssetFiles'`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am posting a solution to my question. Because if anyone is facing this without knowing the difference between `npx react-native start` vs `react-native start`

**Solution:** `npx react-native start` instead of `react-native start`

**Explain:** (Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62067116/9877424)

There are currently two CLIs:

- `@react-native-community/cli` – the one used directly by react-native. That makes it a transitive dependency of your project.
- `react-native-cli` – an optional global convenience package, which is a proxy to @react-native-community/cli and global installation helper.

The global version is no longer recommended

- `npx` executes  either from a local `node_modules/.bin`, or from a central cache, installing any packages needed in order for  to run.
- When you run `npx ...` it picks up the cli package that is part of your project dependency